# Find name of Active Directory domain controller

Tags: active-directory

How can I find out the name/IP address of the AD domain controller on my network?

Comment: DNS should be there exactly for this purpose. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816587/en-us http://www.petri.co.il/active_directory_srv_records.htm

Comment: Very short and sweet [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/354210/465053) from a related thread on SO

Answer (score 178, accepted):

On any computer, that has DNS configured to use AD's DNS server do:

- Start -> Run -> `nslookup`

  ```
  set type=all
  _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.DOMAIN_NAME
  ```

Replace **DOMAIN_NAME** with the actual domain name e.g. *example.com*. Read more [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816587).

Comment: In the answer above, entering set type=all (in nslookup) allows you to see DNS SRV records.  You could also have typed "set type=SRV", SRV records are how AD advertises itself on the network

Comment: But how can a Windows user find out real domain name? I see everywhere some stupid consumer friendly name containing whitespace and other strange chars.

Comment: nslookup -querytype=all _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.eb.eu     
[as a single line]

Answer (score 84):

For a computer that is a member of a domain the Environment Variable LOGONSERVER contains the name of the DC that authenticated the current user. This is obviously not going to be all DC's in a multi-DC environment but if all you want is a quick way to find the name of a Domain Controller then from a command shell:

```
set l <enter>
```

Will return all Environment variables that start with "L" including the name of a DC.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. After obtaining the name of the DC, just ping it to get the IP.

Comment: simple yes, but if you have a VPN connection to the network you are interested in, LOGONSERVER doesn't give you that.  The accepted answer will give you the right server in all cases I can think of.

Comment: It's not perfect, but sometimes it's important also to know how to do something that's good enough quickly. It also fails for local logons but I never checked it over VPN, good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 63):

An unmentioned, super easy, and quick option is to run this from a command prompt:

```
nltest /dclist:domainname
```

Just replace 'domainname' with your domain

You can also run some other options to find out more:

`/dcname:domainname` gets the PDC name for the domain
`/dsgetdc:domainname` has flags for other information

Try `nltest /?` in your prompt to get more options! :)

Comment: `C:\> nltest /dclist:domainname  
Cannot find DC to get DC list from.Status = 1355 0x54b 
ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN  
The command completed successfully`  
What does that mean?

Comment: Replace domainname with the name of your domain

Comment: Oh. That's what I thought this was going to find for me.

Comment: This was super useful for me because [Bash# host -t srv _ldap._tcp.MYCOMPANY] said domain not found. 
[CMD:\> nltest /dclist:MYCOMPANY] told me that the domain name was corp.ad.mycompany.com, and then I was able to use that info to make the other commands work. 
[Bash# host -t srv _ldap._tcp.corp.ad.mycompany.com] then worked

Answer (score 22):

From a Windows command prompt, run `gpresult`. You will get:

- General workstation and domain information
- For both the **computer** and the **user**:

  - Distinguished name in AD and which DC the policy was applied from
  - Applied Group Policy objects
  - List of security groups a member of

Here is [some analysis of `gpresult` output](http://tburke.net/info/reskittools/topics/gpresult_output.htm). You can also specify `gpresult /z` to get more detailed information.

Comment: Wow, `gpresult /Z` outputs a LOT of data. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

This will return your closest Domain Controller in Powershell:

```cs
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
(Get-ADDomainController -DomainName <Domain FQDN> -Discover -NextClosestSite).HostName
```

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work on Windows 10, not even "install-module ..." . Maybe it requires Server or something?

Comment: You would need to install the RSAT tools for Active Directory for this to work from Windows 10: https://www.petri.com/how-to-install-the-remote-server-administration-tools-in-windows-10

Answer (score 17):

DNS and DHCP are the best way to check since there can be Unix/Linux machines on the network managed by the AD domain controller or acting as the domain controller.

Plus, considering active directory is nothing more than Microsoft's version of Kerberos, LDAP, dhcp and dns. It would be better to understand and debug things at lower layers than layer 7+. This is because the operating system would preform these same requests and the underlining RFC for each protocol actually operates at a OSI level not the "insert favorite tool here" level.

One can go a step further and query the dhcp for options 6, 15, and 44 to get the [domain name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.17), [domain name server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.5), and [Wins/NetBIOS name server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.5).

Then using dns to check for the _kerberos._tcp, _kpasswd._tcp, _LDAP._TCP.dc._msdcs, and _ldap._tcp SRV records:

```
nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.EXMAPLE.COM
nslookup -type=srv _kpasswd._tcp.EXAMPLE.COM
nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.EXAMPLE.COM
nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.EXAMPLE.COM

.EXAMPLE.COM ::= value returned from dhcp option-1
```

This breaks down into three areas, two are protocol supported DNS-SD records:

- `_kerberos._tcp` and `_kpasswd._tcp` (also under UNIX/Linux/OSX+some windows networks has `_kadmin._tcp`) are for kerberos
- `_ldap._tcp` is for ldap (openldap, opendc, sun/oracle directory, ms ad)
  `_LDAP._TCP.dc._msdcs` is the Microsoft only extension to ldap to map the domain controller.

Answer (score 4):

## Crude CMD

### Just find DC names

Save as `GetDcNames.cmd`:

```
nslookup -type=any %userdnsdomain%.
```

Run as: `GetDcNames.cmd`.

(Note: The trailing dot in `%userdnsdomain%.` is on purpose. It stops your local nslookup from using any DNS search path strings.)

### Find more AD related DNS domains

I whipped up a quick and dirty batch file, so that I don't have to remember the DNS domain names and/or have to type them all. (List may not be complete.)

Works from domain joined machines. If your machine is not domain joined, then you must manually set USERDNSDOMAIN to what you want.

Save as `TestAdDnsRecords.cmd`:

```
@setlocal
@REM Test AD DNS domains for presence.
@REM For details see: http://serverfault.com/a/811622/253701

nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.%userdnsdomain%.
nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._udp.%userdnsdomain%.
@echo .

nslookup -type=srv _kpasswd._tcp.%userdnsdomain%.
nslookup -type=srv _kpasswd._udp.%userdnsdomain%.
@echo .

nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.%userdnsdomain%.
@echo .

nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.%userdnsdomain%.
@echo .

nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.%userdnsdomain%.
@echo .

@REM Those next few lines here are forest specific:
@REM Change the next line if your current domain is not also the forest root.
@SET "DNSFORESTNAME=%USERDNSDOMAIN%"

nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.%DNSFORESTNAME%.
@echo .

nslookup -type=srv _gc._tcp.%DNSFORESTNAME%.
```

Run as `TestAdDnsRecords.cmd | more`. There is a lot of text output.

## Sources

- MSDN "ServerGeeks" blog, 2014-07-12, Habibar Rahman, [*DNS Records that are required for proper functionality of Active Directory*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servergeeks/2014/07/12/dns-records-that-are-required-for-proper-functionality-of-active-directory/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/LO2aw).)
- TechNet, *Resource Kits > Distributed Systems Guide > Desktop Configuration Management > Active Directory > Name Resolution in Active Directory > Locating Active Directory Servers > [SRV Resource Records](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx)* (Archived [here](https://archive.is/6YZsK).)

Answer (score 1):

If you just have access to DNS, you can get a list of all DCs by the following query in PowerShell:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.<YOU_DOMAIN> -Type SRV
```

This can be done by any user with access to DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt and type "net time" - it will fetch you Domain Controller name along with time.
Example - "Current time at \{DCName} is {time}.

Comment: Cute idea. Although it took a full minute to return when I tried it, and gave the same result as `set log` does. To make it return immediately, use `net time /domain`